# angular auth interceptor on selected request

Tags: angularjs

I have written an auth interceptor that adds auth token to the request and handles auth errors if the user is not logged in.

```
var storeApp = angular.module('storeApp');

storeApp.factory('authInterceptor', function ($q, $window) {
    return {
        request: function (config) {
            config.headers = config.headers || {};
            if ($window.sessionStorage.token) {
                config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $window.sessionStorage.token;
            }
            return config;
        },
        response: function (response) {
            return response || $q.when(response);
        },
        responseError: function (response) {
            if (response.status === 401 || response.data.error === 'token_not_provided') {
                console.log('auth error');
            }
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    };
});

storeApp.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
});
```

The issue is the auth interceptor is added to every request, regardless the request requires authentication or not.  What is the best way to create an auth interceptor that only intercepts when the route requires authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the filter out the requests you want in the authInterceptor factory methods

```
['/whatever/1', '/whatever/2', '/whatever/3'].forEach(function(value){
 if (response.config.url.startsWith(value)) {
   // do something
 }
})


return response;
```